# Prove that if the functions$ f, g \in O(C)$ are such that $\lim_{z→∞} f(g(z)) = \infty$, then $f$ and $g$ are polynomials.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Prove that if the functions $f, g \in O(\mathbb{C})$ are such that
>   $\lim_{z→∞} f(g(z)) = \infty$, then $f$ and $g$ are polynomials.

First, notice that $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}g(z)=\infty$, because if not, then $f$ would not be entire.

I have no idea how can I move further with that problem. Can you give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

For the function $g$, the singularity at $\infty$ can be

- removable; then $g$ is bounded, hence constant, $g(z)=c$, and $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(g(z))=f(c)\ne\infty$
- essential; then by Picard's theorem $g$ takes almost all values $\in \mathbb C$ in every neighbourhood of $\infty$; especially, $f(z_n)=c$ for a suitable $c\in\mathbb C$ and sequence $z_n\to\infty$ and then as above $f(g(z_n))\to f(c)\ne\infty$.
- or a pole; Then $g$ is meromorphic on the complete Riemann sphere, hence is rational, and by the lack of poles at finite places is a polynomial.

Once we know this about $g$, we see by more or less the same argument that the singularity of $f$ at infinity is also a pole, hence $f$ is also a polynomial.